# Download a file from FTP servers by just clicking FTP URLs after almost all browsers remove FTP support?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ftp

Since a few days ago I've noticed that I can't download files from FTP by clicking the URLs. Yesterday I was told that Chrome has removed FTP support and was suggested to download files via FTP clients. It gets quite annoying. To download a file via any FTP client needs a lot more clicks. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install an FTP client that registers to handle `ftp://` URL.

For example *my* [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) does that.

For details, see the article about handling [Protocol URL addresses](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url).

If you want to specify a default credentials for a specific FTP server, you can save a site named after the FTP server hostname in WinSCP GUI along with the credentials. See the [Handling URL addresses](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url#handling) section.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I could have never found this feature by myself. Maybe you could add some hint in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

FTP support in the Chrome browser can be enabled using an experimental (and temporary)
flag:

- Enter `chrome://flags` in the address bar
- Type `FTP` in the search field to find "Enable support for FTP URLs"
- Set the flag to "Enabled"
- Restart Chrome.

This flag was supposed to be removed from Chrome 82, but it's still there today
in version 87.

When the flag will disappear in the future, Chrome will transfer the link to an
FTP client, if one is installed.

Comment: Are you able to use a non-chrome browser - such as Firefox?

Comment: Thanks. The flag works great. I wish it would stay forever.

Answer (score 1):

I made this convenient ftp proxy tool in glitch.com since all browsers unanonymously decided to kill ftp support.
You just append it before the ftp address.
http://sofetchpost.glitch.me/ftp://ftp.fau.de/apache/

if the ftp server is not publicly available on the web, you can just fork the project and host it yourself, with whatever network requirements that you need. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**From [FTP Access Through Windows Explorer](https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/201637914-FTP-Access-through-Windows-Explorer)** article

- Open Control Panel via your start menu and double click on Internet Options.
- Select the Advanced tab at the top and scroll down to Enable FTP
  folder view (outside of Internet Explorer) and make sure it is
  checked.
- Scroll down to Use Passive FTP (for Firewall and DSL modem
  compatibility) and make sure it is checked. Click OK to save these
  settings.
- Open the File Explorer on Windows.
- Click on This PC from the left navigation panel in Windows Explorer,    then click on Computer from the top, after that you will open the    ribbon menu, choose **Add a network location**. You can also right-click on This PC, then choose Add a network location from the jump-down context menu.
- The Add Network Location Wizard will open; click Next.
- Select the Choose another network location option and click Next.
- Enter the FTP address for your domain, e.g., ftp://ftp-acme.egnyte.com (replace acme with your domain name).
- Click Next.